# python calculate table without (numpy)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i have a quick question about finding line # from my text and
use this line# to calculate something

(this is not hw question and i just start learning about python)

ex~
if my text looks like

```
 100 200 300
 400 500 600 
 700 800 900
 120 130 140
 150 160 170
```

and

```
f1 = open('sample4.txt','r')

line_num = 0
search_phrase = "100"

for line in f1.readlines():
line_num += 1
if line.find(search_phrase) >= 0:
    x = line_num
    print (x)

import numpy
data = numpy.loadtxt('sample4.txt')
print(data[x:x+3,1].sum())
```

i could get

```
1430.0 which is (200+500+800+130)
```

however, if my text looks like:

```
apple is good
i dont like apple
100 200 300 
400 500 600 
700 800 900
120 130 140 
150 160 170
i love orange
```

error pops up and said

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Python33/sample4.py", line 13, in <module>
 data = numpy.loadtxt('sample4.txt')
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 827, in loadtxt
 items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
 File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 827, in <listcomp>
 items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'apple'
```

i think the reason why this error pops up becasue **NUMPY**

is there any way to make this correct?? 
without using some skip_header or skip_footer

Comment: Could the lines with text appear anywhere in your file, or always at the beginning? What don't you like about skipping a few lines when you read the file in?

Comment: You can pass something to the optional argument `dtype` in `np.loadtxt`.  (`dtype` defaults to float which is why you're seeing the error)

Comment: As a side note, look at the [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function if you want to get the line number of each line; it's much easier (and more robust) than trying to keep track of it explicitly.

Comment: lines with text appear anywhere in my file.  i have 500 different data text file and all text file have 1200~1233 lines and i do not want to find line# each time to calculate some numbers :(( i found the way to use                                                   data = numpy.genfromtxt('filename', skip_header=981, skip_footer=215, usecols=[1]), but too much work for 500 files :((

Comment: I don't see how what you are attempting would be any better than the skip_header/skip_footer approach. What do you mean by "too much work for 500 files"? You would be doing that programmatically, right? (As you are attempting now.) 500 files with 1200 lines is not that much. If you need to do this many times you can put the data in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that loadtxt can use a file handle as input, so one (maybe ugly) trick might be to first determine the line of your interesting text as you did, then reopen the file, read the first few uninteresting lines and then pass the file handle to loadtxt (untested):

```
fname = 'sample4.txt'
search_phrase = '100'

with open(fname) as fid:
    for linenum, line in enumerate(fid):
        if search_phrase in line:
            break #if the n-th line is interesting, line_num = n-1

#reopen file
with open(fname) as fid:
    for i in xrange(linenum):
        fid.readline() #throw away uninteresting lines
    data = np.loadtxt(fid) #pass file handle

print(data[:3,1].sum()) #interesting stuff is now in first row
```

But what is wrong with using skiprows? The second part could then be changed into

```
#get linenum as before
data = np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows = linenum)
print(data[:3,1].sum()) #interesting stuff is now in first row
```

Comment: thank you for explaining ~ just quick question that the value error pops up if i put new line "i love orange" at the bottom :(( what should i do.?   ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'i'